# Neuralnet in R utilizing GPU

Tags: r, neural-network, gpu

Is there a way to get the neuralnet package in R to start utilizing my GPU to speed it up?

I have tried installing other packages like gpuR and TensorFlow but the neuralnet function doesnt seem to be interacting with them.

Answer (score 2):

There are some packages that allow you to run parallel tasks in R (i.e., http://www.parallelr.com/r-gpu-programming-for-all-with-gpur/), but they are mostly focused on math operations like linear algebra. Unfortunately, at the time of writing this answer, there is no way to to run the **neuralnet** library using a GPU.

An alternative is to install the more recently developed **TensorFlow for R** package, which would allow you to use an Nvidia GPU. The documentation could be found at: https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/tools/local_gpu.html